# Outlook 2010- figuring out who cancelled a meeting and when

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

I fear my boss is setting me up to take the fall for several cancelled meetings.  She claims I cancelled them when I shouldn't have.  I have not done this, obviously.  In fact, I keep a record of all cancellations on my own calendar for this exact purpose.  If something "disappears" it is because someone else cancelled or deleted it.  I need to find out if there is a way to determine who cancelled a meeting and when.  I need to be able to determine this on a calendar that is Shared to me, not on MY calendar.  I hope that makes sense.  Is this possible?

I am her admin, So I can add, create and cancel meetings on her behalf. I fear she is accidentally or purposefully deleting items off her calendar, not necessarily canceling them. Then when the time comes she wants to know why it is not on her calendar. We are talking dozens of times this has happened. And I know it's not on my end and I can't figure out a way to prevent it in the future.

Comment: Outlook treats attendees and organizers differently. If you're an attendee you are notified when cancellation occurs - so it's a matter of not deleting those notifications (which will keep them in calendar). If you're an organizer, then tough luck. First, only the organizer can cancel the meeting or update it. Secondly, cancelling a meeting means it's being deleted, and if you want to keep it, you have to restore it. But Outlook will then treat is as a meeting and will try sending notifications or cancels when modified.

Comment: Welcome to superuser. You can *always* edit your own question to add information or to clarify things, or to use comments for more minor things. You can post an answer if you find a solution yourself, but unlike a forum, you generally don't need to/shouldn't reply to your own initial question. Have a read of the [tour] and [help] for a better idea of how we do things.

Answer (score 1):

Meeting cancellations are sent out as emails with a specific outlook form so if your calendar were copied into the meeting request, you would have a record. The cancellation messages are deleted by default once you've acknowledged them but I think you can turn that off in Options.

In your case though, you won't get those since you are only looking at a shared calendar, the owner of the calendar will get cancellations for messages they didn't set up. Entries they originated have no record of deletion except that the calendar form will end up in the deleted items folder until that is cleared out.

One possible approach might be, if you are arranging meetings, to do it from your own mailbox and include the other mailbox as an invitee. Or alternatively, do it the other way around. Create the invite in the shared calendar but include yourself as an attendee. Then you get any cancellation message. Note however that it is possible for a user to suppress any attendee update messages.

The only other options I can think of either involve changing permissions to prevent someone from deleting things or writing a Macro to keep track of actions.

UPDATE: I think you will have to go old-school. Print off her schedule regularly so that you have a printed record of everything and then monitor her calendar closely.

The other thing would be to report the missing entries as a fault to your IT department. Don't tell them about your fears of course, but armed with the print outs push the problem to them. It is possible that they will discover her doing something wrong and then they get to make a fuss rather than you. If you do get evidence of wrong doing, plan on how you would blow the whistle on her but be ready to look for another job.

To be honest, if you don't trust her, you are really in the wrong role anyway - time for something new if you can - though I realise that might not be so easy.

Comment: Organizer may cancel without sending updates. Also, only organizer can cancel meeting. Shared calendar means its admin or owner can delete meeting, but not cancel. and last - if organizer will include himself as an attendee, wouldn't it remove him as an organizer?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned point1. If you have delegated rights you can create a meeting for someone else - we really need to know exactly how danielle and her boss manage the calendar. The organiser cannot include themselves as they are always a required attendee unless creating a delegated event.

Comment: You're right. Sorry. And delegated access would mess things up. But let's analyse what she wrote: cancelling meetings without noticing anyone on shared calendar. She could cancel meeting only if she has delegated access (thanks for pointing that to me; I forgot completely). Which I assume she does not, she just has access to shared calendar. So if that's the case, it's rather easy to determine: she cannot cancel another's meeting not being organizer. Only delete or amend. One has to look in each persons (with this level of sharing) Deleted item folder...

Comment: I hope this makes sense. I am her admin, So I can add, create and cancel meetings on her behalf. I fear she is accidentally or purposefully deleting items off her calendar, not necessarily canceling them. Then when the time comes she wants to know why it is not on her calendar. We are talking dozens of times this has happened. And I know it's not on my end and I can't figure out a way to prevent it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the event and click on the Message Options | Properties feature, you can look at the internet header to see who sent the cancellation. It will show you the date the email was sent, who it is from and who it was sent to.